# In which way the set command can be involved?

Tags: batch-file, file-io, cmd, io-redirection

I have a text file named `fruit.txt` with the content:

> ```
> apples
> bananas
> mango
> ```

For a `cmd` output through batch input redirection I chose the following code:

```
@echo off
(
    set /p line_1=
    set /p line_2=
    set /p line_3=
)<fruit.txt
echo fruit 1 is %line_1%, fruit 2 is %line2% and fruit 3 is %line_3%
```

For a redirection with the `>` key a text file content can be replaced.

```
echo Content > Textfile.txt
```

With only my logic I assume to find a way to do this with the `<` key on the `cmd` command line.

Batch files have addresses `%0`, `%1`, `shift` etc. named parameter. A batch file named `found.bat` with the command:

```
echo %1
pause > nul
```

...can be called also without `call` command, through a second batch file named `to connect.bat`:

```
found.bat adress
```

My question is to find a way to use the adress for input with the `<` key? The `cmd` output should be replaced in a similar way the content of a text file can be replaced.

The Batch Code i use to start my Input Research is mostly one file with the Content

```
    echo apples bananas mango > "fruit".txt
    echo apples citron ingwer >> "fruit".txt
    X.bat < "fruit".txt
```

and a second one in this case named X.bat including

```
    sort
    pause > nul
```

To start the two Batch files for a cmd prompt Screen Output you have to use the cmd prompt, if you are usually open a file in a Desktop Environment. I do not know why for this case it has to be done that way.

The Parameter %1 in the second Batch file is connected to a on Switch adressed in this case with the sort command.

Comment: Can you reword the question. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question. `set /p` gets input from STDIN (normally the keyboard). The redirection redirects the contents of a file to STDIN, so `set /p` can receive it. Normally, this way is used for very short files (one line, maybe two). To read a file, [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is to be preferred.

Comment: I read your question several times, but I have no clue what you want to know. Please reword it completely and also provide sample data of your text file(s)...

Comment: I am searching for a way to connect a variable to cmd ouput to Change the Output while runtime. A value through a variable can be written to a Textfile with the >> or > key. I try to to find a way to do this for a cmd ouput with a < key Input.

Comment: I am even more confused now. The content of text file `fruit.txt` are three lines, right?

Comment: Yes and i aim to replace for example mango on the cmd command line output.

Comment: @ledlightjungled, what has this got to with argument references `%0`, `%1`, `%2`, etc.?

Comment: @ledlightjungled, I do not see any code in your example that is trying to change the data.

Comment: While i am on the search for redirection possibilities i asume a way to adress the parameter %1 right to the Batch name and also (what i cannot do now) to adress the parameter inside a Batch file to reach from inside a Batch file the cmd command prompt. I just can think of this possibility because i can reach inside a Textfile with a > key.

Comment: @ledlightjungled, two suggestions for you. 1) Provide an example of your input and what you want as your output. 2) Tag people you are replying to so that they get a notification that you have answered their question.

Comment: The command Code followed is to be used with two Batch files. File one...    echo apples bananas mango > "fruit".txt
             echo apples citron ingwer >> "fruit".txt
             X.bat < "fruit".txt                                                               File two...     sort
             pause > nul

Comment: This Code can be executed for visibility with the command prompt executing the first Batch file. The sort command in the second Batch file is connected or a saved Adresse like a on Switch with the %1 parameter. I try to build a Code connected to the %1 in the second Batch file that changes the Content in the command prompt Output with the < key like the > key is used through the fruit.txt Textfile. If it is not possible to find a answer i am not sorry. It´s ok. I am searching for more than two years and maybe one day i find a solution.

Comment: @ledlightjungled, do not put extra code into a comment.  Edit your question with code updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use `%1` etc (what are parameters to the batch file), then you have to call the batchfile with parameters. `x.bat < fruit.txt` redirects the content of fruit.txt to STDIN - which has nothing in common with parameters.

first:

```
echo apples bananas mango > "fruit".txt
echo apples citron ingwer >> "fruit".txt
X.bat "fruit.txt"
```

second (x.bat):

```
sort %1
pause
```

If this doesn't answer your question (or at least turns you into the right direction), please reword your question. This answer is mainly based on guessing, what you tried to ask.

Comment: Guessing is the main part for this work done with the known skeleton command prompt, when it is in use.
The whole mysterie is the source code command prompt is written. A study would be easier with a source code.
I will try to focus my work on less points to be to connect also while rewording my task.

Comment: No Time is not a part in a Comment Add Form. To Stop a Part Form no Step is in a Way. I Need a On Hold Command Line to Fit A Part Not Used Through Clear Screen.